# 4.5v to 3v with a resistor

Tags: voltage

I have some christmas lights powered by 3 x 1.5v AA batteries, but the label shows they need 3v 0.06w.  Taking apart the very small circuit board I can see they are stepped down with a resistor.  Other questions here say quite simply - don't do this as you cannot guarantee the load etc.  which makes sense.

My problem has been that the lights will be at differing brightness when they all have fresh batteries, plus they only last a few days before I need to replace the batteries when I have another set of battery powered LED lights that will last for a month (at 6 hours per day).  I'm partly guessing the quality of the resistor is highly variable - but electronics is really not my area of expertise!

So the questions: does the use of a resistor have a detrimental effect on battery life?  Would replacing the pack with a simple switched 2 x AA battery pack improve things (so no need to try and drop voltage)?  Or how can I power more than one set of these lights from a transformer?

Comment: Presumably these are not LED lights?

Comment: Yes they are LED lights.  The label says "30 bulbs x 3V 0.06W"

Comment: The label is a little ambiguous, but I've left an answer below. A 60 mW LED is reasonable, but if you have 30 of them your AA battery shouldn't last as long as it does..!

Comment: @DavidLester: Do you have access to a multimeter? If so, can you take a current reading and measure the resistor value and include the results in your question?

Comment: As the voltage drops the current draw drops, and the life of the batteries increases. Days is not unusual.

Comment: Don't trust those labels. They aren' precise.

Comment: @Transistor - I've got a very old analogue avometer 8 which to be honest I don't know how to work properly and certainly can't read the results with any degree of acuracy! I'll go buy something better to get some readings.  When I plugged it across to read the current it drained the batteries instantly though.

Comment: @DavidLester: You take current readings by inserting the meter in series with the load - not directly across the battery which effectively short-circuits them and risks damaging the meter.

Comment: @Transistor - Thanks for (accurately!) assuming I know nothing at all!  New multimeter means I can maybe answer some questions now!  Resistor shows as 10ohms.  Batteries (used!) are showing 3.6v.  current looks like 1.2uA - does that all sound correct?

Comment: I also tried to measure the voltage across the resistor (with the lights on) and it measures 0.22v - I'm assuming that's the drop?  and lastly the cr2032 battery shows 2.6v but somehow just 0.2uA?  I'm not sure I'm measuring things correctly!

Comment: The cr2032 has a high internal resistance so that makes sense. At 10 ohms, and 0.22V, that should be 22 mA, milliamps not microamps (1 mA = 1000 ųA).

Answer (score 1):

> does the use of a resistor have a detrimental effect on battery life?

Partly. There is a voltage drop across the resistor which means wasted power. But this is required for proper operation in your setup.

> Would replacing the pack with a simple switched 2 x AA battery pack improve things (so no need to try and drop voltage)?

Yes and no. Remove the resistor and if the voltage is less than the VF at 20mA, then the leds will be fine. You may have a shorter battery life as you essentially removed 1/3 the power, but it may be longer. You have to measure to see.

> Or how can I power more than one set of these lights from a transformer?

Get a 4.5V or 3.3V power supply, and wire it in place of the batteries. That's it. A 4.5V supply will look brighter. Or use a usb power supply. The leds will be even brighter, as the current increased, so the led life may drop, or you can add a resistor or 1n400x diode to make it go down by 0.7V or 2 for 1.4V. Perfect for your string.

I've done this, a usb port to a diode to one of the led strings with a timer. Running for a year straight no issues.

Comment: I think a transformer is the way to go - the question for me is - how?  Can I run all from a single transformer?  I have one that is adjustable showing 2500mA at 3/4.5/5v.  Can I just plug that into some kind of wiring loom and have running to 4 sets?  I'm guessing I need it wired in parallel?

Comment: Yes, wire them in parallel. Since the board expects 4.5V you dont have to do anything else either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the lights are no where near 2.5 amp so that adapter is perfect. Ideally you would want to measure them to be sure,  but meh

Comment: So I think I will want use the lead that holds the CR2032 cable.  It's got a handy plug on the end that goes into the main battery unit but bypasses the resistor so I guess I'd run that as 3v?  Just need a selection of wires, a box to hold it, and a socket on the box that will take the adapter I guess!

Comment: I just make a notch in the battery cover and use that. No need to bypass the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The resistor isn't there to drop voltage, it actually limits the current. LEDs (to a first approximation) effectively become short circuits once the voltage across them reaches a certain value. The current through the LEDs will drop as the battery voltage drops with just a resistor, so the intensity of the LEDs will gradually go down.

The resistor does waste power, but for this usage case it would be difficult or impossible to use a more efficient solution without significantly increasing the cost. Resistor quality is not really a consideration, unless the resistor is truly terrible and then it would probably just pop.

Two AA batteries probably won't have high enough voltage to make the LEDs conduct at all so you can't do that. A 5 V adaptor would probably be fine, although you'd have to check the power rating of the resistor.

Comment: Thanks - although that leaves me more confused!  Why does it state they are "3v" and yet I have 4.5v from the batteries?  Also - there is a "tester" battery (from when they were in the packaging - hold the button and see them light up) that connects via a seperate lead.  This is powered by a single CR2032 3v battery and i can see that this will bypass the resistor.

Comment: Ok, so when the voltage across the LED is 3V, it will light up but looks like a short circuit and so a large current would flow and it would go pop (sometimes literally). You have 4.5 V, and the resistor. You can calculate the current (and hence light level) using those figures. \$ I = \frac{V_{battery} - V_{LED}}{R} \$. Does that make sense?

Comment: CR2032 can power maybe 1 or 2 LED at low current and has internal resistance and wont last long. ( very Dim maybe >24hr after a couple hr half-bright) If they use 4.5V then they must have resistor in series added. (hidden)

Comment: Your are mistaken to claim that "The resistor does not impact the efficiency in this simple usage case" - in fact it very much does.  The amount of power wasted may be small, but the efficiency is most definitely reduced by this, likely by quite a lot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I specifically said "simple usage case", because while you absolutely can make it more efficient if you're selling Christmas lights you can't afford to. I've altered the wording slightly to reflect that.

Comment: I should clarify - they would run for say 8 hours per day, but need the batteries replacing after say 4/5 days (if memory serves) - which starts to get very expensive running 3 x AA alkaline batteries on 4 sets of lights.  The CR2032 option is only for the demo in the packet - only on for as long as you hold the switch.  So no idea how long it would last - only that the brightness is comparable to the 3 x AA solution but that the CR2032 doesn't go via the resistor - hence I wondered if 2 x AA without a resistor would be preferable and certainly hoped they would last longer.

Comment: @awjlogan Actually the resistor does both, drops V and limits current and Ohms Law can be used as I have shown.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Of course it drops V, but that's not the primary role here. If I used a supply with just over the forward voltage of the diode and no resistor, it would still burn the LED. It's just unfortunate that power is wasted.

Comment: @awjlogan  Burn? Not true!  unless you mean 3.3 is "just over" 3V ... All  diodes have ESR,  5mm White ~ 16 ohms +/-25% for most...

Comment: @DavidLester  If I had to choose a battery , it would be a 18650 LiPo Cell at 3.6V with 1500mAh or ~5Wh.  and then Vdrop in R is only 0.5 to 0.6V but still not enough to meet your expectations ,

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I do mean something like 3.3V being "just over" - they're trying to run it from a battery, so the input voltage will be all over the place. Unless you use a regulator, and then you'll just lose your power there instead. Your suggestion simply moves the problem of current limiting elsewhere.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Besides, trying to tune your voltage to just above the LED voltage is definitely not a good plan unless you want to handpick your LEDs.

Comment: Poor quality LEDs only have a wide tolerance due to higher ESR than I stated so current will be less than above.  Most 5mm LED white chips are improved these days, unless one buys rejects off Ebay without awareness. For example you can stick ANY 5mm White LED directly to a 3.0V Lithium CR123A cell and the current will always be < 20mA. Normally I choose a series R=0 for all my LEDs since I get excellent consistency ( single bin 3.0~3.1 V LEDs )  This based on my experience in last 10 yrs from multiple sources in TW,CN and ~ 100k parts/yr

Comment: 30P LEDs (//) results in ESR of 16ohm/Q=30 ~ 0.5 ohm. and unless overdriven there wont be thermal runaway from same batch.  Battery ESR must also be considered.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 There's a problem though. There's absolutely no way to guarantee a "single bin" source, or even batch. Sure, for white LEDs with a coin cell, it's probably fine but that's not an option if you're making a million, which in this instance they almost certainly are. And what if someone decides (like the OP) to use an external supply with a lower internal resistance than a coin cell? I don't doubt your method works, but I wouldn't call it best practice.

Comment: I've sold over a million LEDs without issues , but then I choose my sources.  Again ESR variance is always on the high side from typical.  andESR=k/Pd with k~1 for 5mm k=0.5 for better high power ones  CR123A ESR is very low but then Vb=3.0V , Lipo even lower ESR 5 to 50mohm  but then Vb=3.7 to 3V

Comment: Manufactures do make millions of 2x AA no resistor led strings of multiple white or blue leds in parallel without issue. And if someone decides to stick a power supply in it, they will refuse to warrant it. That's a non issue, it doesn't happen even 0.1% of the time of their millions of units sold.

Comment: @Passerby I feel we've got away from the OP's original question and scenario, to which my answer is still reasonable (I think!).

Comment: @awjlogan  your answer is flawed in the details using Ohm's law with LED ESR (Vf=Vth+I*ESR)  being used with fixed R with variable Vbat that drops below rated Vf with unused capacity.  3.3V fixed or 3.7V Lipo is better with suitable Rs by SOT ( Select on Test) then determined life time from battery with useful voltage range and load power. which are partially addressed in my answer.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Of course it's an approximation, but do you think an Xmas light manufacturer will pay for specially selected LEDs? For them, customers can get AA batteries wherever, 2 AA batteries is too low V, so 3 AA batteries it is.

Comment: @awjlogan  that was not my point, your initial statement is wrong.  All diodes function with series Rs to drop voltage which in turn determines its current load.  You said *it isn't there to drop voltage* is a technically flawed statement.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I take your point, my phrasing isn't great. I'll make an edit on it :)

Answer (score -2):

> 1. does the use of a resistor have a detrimental effect on battery life?
>
>    2. Would replacing the pack with a simple switched 2 x AA battery pack improve things (so no need to try and drop voltage)?
>    3. Or how can I power more than one set of these lights from a transformer?

---

> 1. only if it is the wrong value?
>
>    2. It would save wasted power from series drop of 1 to 1.5V to 3V or 30% to 50% loss but then may not be full brightness
>    3. Much wiser solution.  Buy a brick matched to voltage and current of the load, *which has yet to be defined* except ~3V with roughly 30 LEDs in some disarray

### Engineering wisdom

A string of LEDs will not last very long on Alkaline batteries. If you expect 30 5mm LEDs to be bright for 6hrs a day for a month, it wont happen with a few Alkaline AA batteries, rather 8 day and dimming slowly during that day.

Consider AC-DC supply only or Lithium CR123A (Primary 3.0V) or LiPo (secondary 3.6V with small R depending on number of LEDs in parallel.

White LEDs

- 3.1V full brightness  **equivalent to 2.8V + If[20ma] * 16 Ohms** (per LED)
- 2.9V half bright
- 2.8V dim
- 2.7V nearly off

One 5mm White LED is rated at 3~3.1V @ 20mA = 0.06 W.  How many do you have sharing this power?

If 0.06W per LED x30  implies total power of 1.8W at full brightness.   AA Alkaline cells are about 3Wh using 100mA rates but voltage declines to <1V  so how many hours did you expect and  at what power level?  Thus you might expect a few hrs at this power range then dim quickly and be sustained for a much longer period.  With 30 LEDs I expect them to be arranged as 1S30P so the series R for 30 parallel strings of say 10mA each to drop 1V is 1V/0.3A= 3.3 ohms

300 mA ^2 * 3.3 ohms = Pd = 0.3W so use a 0.5W R

When batteries are fresh the Vdrop=1.4 to 3.1V LEDs with 3.3R in series is then 1.4V/0.3ohm= 420 mA /30 = 14 mA or <50mW per LED so this works for  while.

Comment: So the label says 30 LED's but hard to count them as they are arranged hap-hazardly on a star shape.

Comment: I wonder who and why some disagreed with my information.  It is obvious one needs to regulate current and a resistor can be a simple but less than perfect method.  The choice of batteries is poor. (does not meet spec for time)